# split-view with "scroll" detail view

Tags: ipad

I have a problem. I need put over the main menu the detail view on SplitView.

The Detail view Scroll can see in Twitter app for iPad.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RIJTXNfGHuM

Some idea?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just add in your detail view a scrolView

```
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

and in your DetailViewController.m

```
self.scroller.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(something,something)];
```